# Problem with importing JS modules on Flask server

Tags: javascript, flask

I run a Flask server to work with Firebase Storage and Firestore using Python, but I need to integrate a Firebase Auth in my frontend somehow. So, I've managed to run an external JS script in Jinja template, but I can't import anything in it. (404 Not Found error)

I've tried many combinations, but what should I do to make it work?

I've tried many combinations of import string, starting from "firebase/app" and up to:

"../../../node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index"

and

"../../../node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index.d.ts"

But the problem remains.

I've added `static_url_path='/static'` to Flask(), but that does seem to help.

Comment: https://chat.openai.com/share/de24e01d-899e-4a71-b73b-8055e74649c5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Managed to resolve import using CDN:
[Firebase CDN](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup)

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.0.0/firebase-app.js';
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-auth.js';
```

Answer (score 2):

Flask does not allow directory transversal in static file locations.  All the files must be located in the `static` directory.

Options are:

1. Copy the firebase dist files into a folder under `/static` and refer to them using JavaScript import statements or a `src` tag.
2. Create an endpoint in your Flask server to expose the `node_modules/firebase` folder and serve the files from there.

Comment: Hello, I've copied Firebase folder into static, but how do I refer it now? "../firebase/app/dist/app/index" returns 404, "../firebase/app/dist/app/index.d.ts" returns "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."  Wring file or wrong type in script tag?

Comment: That's because the file you are trying to use is TypeScript and will need to be transpiled into JavaScript before use.

Comment: Converted it, now it says: `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../firebase/auth/dist/auth/index.js' does not provide an export named 'getAuth' (at fbAuth.js:2:10)` ,  but it does: https://postimg.cc/Zv0ysY1G

Comment: This is contents of JS, should I do something about this "@firebase" folder?
https://ibb.co/1z29hyX

Comment: You'll have to get the firebase community to help. It's not something I'm familiar with.